# How to implement Android playstore in-app update with react-native

Tags: android, react-native

[image: immediate flow of play store in-app updates]

How can I implement play store in-app update with my react-native app, which is already live on play store?

I have already implemented code push and also internal version check via API calls to force the user to update the app.

With Codepush: code push only works for javascript changes. However, there are many scenarios where we will need the whole app to be updated when there is a native code change.

With API check: We need to watch when the update is getting live, and update the version number kept in the backend to force the user to update the app.

Though both these solutions are kind of patchy, I would like to implement the elegant approach of the play-store in-app update, but couldn't find a clue on how to get it done.

Answer (score 16):

I did not find any react-native package for this, so I had to implement it for my self.

You can check the complete tutorial [here](https://www.naroju.com/implementing-android-in-app-updates-in-react-native/) and below downloadable files [here](https://github.com/sandeshnaroju/react-native-in-app-update).

But in short, here is what you need to do.

1. Open `android` folder in your react-native project with `Android Studio` and add `implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.3'` at the end of dependencies section of the `build.gradle(app)` file. Like below,

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules


    .......
    implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.7.3' // add it at the end
}
```

Cick sync after adding the dependency.

2. Download `InAppUpdateModule.java` and `InAppUpdatePackage.java` files and place in them in the same directory of `MainActivity.java`(`android/app/src/main/java/<package>/`)
3. Change the package names in both `InAppUpdateModule.java` and `InAppUpdatePackage.java` to your project package name.
4. Now Open `MainApplication.java` and add our `InAppUpdatePackage` into `getPackages` method like below,

```
        @Override
        protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
          @SuppressWarnings("UnnecessaryLocalVariable")
          List<ReactPackage> packages = new PackageList(this).getPackages();
          // Packages that cannot be autolinked yet can be added manually here, for example:
           //  packages.add(new MyReactNativePackage());
            packages.add(new InAppUpdatePackage());
          return packages;
        }
```

5. Download `InAppUpdate.js` and place it into your `react-native` project.
6. Import the `InAppUpdate.js` in any `js` file, wherever you want to use. And use it like below.

```
  componentDidMount () {
    InAppUpdate.checkUpdate() // this is how you check for update 
  }
```

7. That's it.

You can download all the files from [here](https://github.com/sandeshnaroju/react-native-in-app-update)

Comment: I've followed the steps and finally while debugging using the link from internal app sharing, its redirected to playstore with my app opened but Install button is missing in it! My app is supported only in US. I'm trying out from a different country. Could that be the reason? Kindly clarify, Thanks

Comment: I replied on my blog. It is normal that you don't see install button from different country.

Comment: This looks promising.. I'll try this.

Comment: @Naroju Thanks for the clarification. After connecting to the store using VPN, it worked perfectly fine!

Comment: @Naroju I followed these steps and uploaded two versions to internal app sharing. After uploading the new version, I can see the button change from "Open" to "Update". However, when I open my app the pop-up does not appear. I have tried many times but can't seem to get the pop-up to show. Do you have any idea why this might be?

Answer (score 3):

There's a fairly new package that does that: [sp-react-native-in-app-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-react-native-in-app-updates).

It also handles the iOS case by prompting the user with a native alert that redirects to the App Store.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sp-react-native-in-app-updates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sp-react-native-in-app-updates) library for inapp update.

```
npm i sp-react-native-in-app-updates
```

This is a react-native native module that works on both iOS and Android, and checks the stores (play/app) for a new version of your app and can prompt your user for an update.

It uses embedded in-app-updates via Play-Core on Android (to check & download google play patches natively from within the app), and react-native-siren on iOS (to check & navigate the user to the AppStore).

Answer (score 0):

One more option (Better than the APi check): 
Check the latest version from play store and act accordingly, with https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check

```
VersionCheck.needUpdate()
  .then(async res => {
    console.log(res.isNeeded);    // true
    if (res.isNeeded) {
      Linking.openURL(await VersionCheck.getStoreUrl());  // open store if update is needed.
    }
  });
```

Comment: Does it automatically detects the updates on every devices if I put updated apk on Play Store?

Comment: As this is a part of code that is triggered from the app in the device, it should be checking the play store version

Comment: -1 for that library. You can see that it implements version-checking for google play [here](https://github.com/kimxogus/react-native-version-check/blob/master/packages/react-native-version-check/src/providers/playStore.js) by parsing the HTML from the app listing. There don't seem to be any great packages that wrap the play store in-app update API, so naroju's answer seems to be the best way to do this right now.